# Static class property, multiple constructors in C++

Tags: c++, class, c++11, static

Say I have

```
class A {
public:
  A();
  A(int);
  static const int foo;
  int bar;
}
```

how do I go about constructing the class if I want the static member to be initialised in the constructor? This:

```
A::A()
{
  foo = 123; 
  bar = 42;
}
A::A(int b)
{
  foo = 123;
  bar = b;
}
```

seems to work, but if the static member `foo` is shared among all the instances of the class, how is it that I can initialise it twice? It just seems like I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: The code doesn't compile. Also, you won't be able to assign to `foo`, because it's `const`-qualified.

Comment: Distinguish initialization and assignment.

Comment: Whoops, `A(bar);` is the constructor, when the class is instantiated with an int as a parameter.

Comment: Which version of C++? (11, 14, 17)?

Comment: IDK, it's actually arduino embedded code, which is a subset of C++ the compiler options include `-std=gnu++11` so I'm guessing 11..?

Comment: @stib correct, that's C++11 with GCC extensions.

Comment: Neither `foo = 123;` nor `bar = 42;` is an initialization. They are **assignments** to variables that have already been initialized by the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C++11:

A static variable has to be defined outside the class in you cpp file, if it can't *be initialized with an initializer in which every expression is a constant expression, right inside the class definition*:

**file.h**

```
class A {
public:
  A();
  A(int);
  static const int foo;
  int bar;
}
```

**file.cpp**

```
const int A::foo = 123;
```

For C++17:

This can be done inlined.

```
class A {
public:
  A();
  A(int);
  inline static const int foo = 123;
  int bar;
}
```

Comment: I thought a static const int could be initlialised inline, even before C++11. Am I wrong?

Comment: Isn't the inlined code valid already in C++03 (at least for integral types)?

Comment: Yes it is true, under the condition that: *it can be initialized with an initializer in which every expression is a constant expression, right inside the class definition*  (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static)

Comment: @john & Walter According to cppreference, yes! https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static under "Constant static members": "If a static data member of integral or enumeration type is declared const (and not volatile), it can be initialized with an initializer in which every expression is a constant expression, right inside the class definition"

Answer (score 3):

Well, yes you are doing something wrong …

first off, a static const member should to be initialized directly in the class declaration (because it is `const` as mentioned in some comments, it can but does not 'need' to be).

But generally speaking, if you have a static class member, you can simply provide an initializer as a forward definition like so:

```
int A::foo = 42;
```

This allows the compiler to init the static member **before** any of your constructors are even called. (This is handled for you by the standard C++ library).

Comment: Since it's static const and an integer it could also be initialised in the class itself. No need for a separate definition.

Comment: because it is `const` it **can** be initialized in the class declaration, but it does not **need** to be initialized in the class declaration

Answer (score 2):

If you have a static member that is not `const`, you can change it anywhere you like, including "in the constructor". It may not make much sense to do so (especially in a constructor that is very strongly coupled to a given class instance), but it's possible.

If the static member is `const` (as in your code), you cannot change it anywhere. You can only initialize it (once). You can either do this directly with the declaration (`const static int foo = 42`) or in the corresponding `.cpp` file (`const int A::foo = 42`).